# Python xml encoding issue

Tags: python, xml

I have some list and i want to save them as XML.But my data contains Turkish characters.So the data looks complicated.

Data Looks:

```
d\\u013,\\u011frulam,\\u011 etc..
```

I tried a lot of method but didn't work.

```
jsonx = json.dumps({'Baslik1': baslikarimks , 'Baslik2':hizmetler, 'Baslik3':altlinklers, 'Baslik4':basliklarx,'Baslik5':eks})

with open('dasd.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsonx, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4,
              ensure_ascii=False)
```

I used also encoding method but still same

```
 encoding='utf-8'
 enconding='utf-8-sig'
```

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things - 1. How are you getting this list? What is the format? 2. Did you test your code to convert this list to xml when list contains only alphabets? 3. What are turkish characters? Can you give an example.

Comment: Hello, i solved with replace. Thanks :)